# Isomorphism between groups of $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I'm stuck on this problem: For $\mu \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ let

$$G_\mu := \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & a^\mu \end{pmatrix} : a \in \mathbb{R}^+, \; b \in \mathbb{R}\right\} .$$
Show that all the groups $G_\mu$ are pairwise isomorphic. Actually, I have no idea of how a group isomorphism $G_\mu \to G_\lambda$, with $\mu \neq \lambda$, can exists.

Comment: Try putting $a^\mu\mapsto a^\lambda$ and the other entries as constant. The idea is that for every $\mu$ the function $a^\mu$ is biyective on $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: @Yotas Trejos If you mean the map $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a^\mu\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a^\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ It was my first idea but it doesn't works. You can check this is not a group isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping the matrix in $G_\mu$ with first row $(a,b)$ to the matrix in $G_\lambda$ with first row $(a^{\frac{\mu-1}{\lambda-1}},ba^{\frac{\mu-\lambda}{\lambda-1}})$ (or something like that).

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: @Fry I see you're a registered user. If you found this answer useful, you can up vote it.